# What does "hands full of gimme" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What are the means of "**hands full of gimme**" ? What means gimme ?

this from a song

```
Republicrats and Democans
It ain't no surprise
Got their hands full of gimme
Got their mouths full of lies

-- Don Edwards - Hard Times In The Country
```

Comment: I don't know _what is the meaning of_ 'hands full of gimme'. You need to tell us where you read or heard this phrase. 'Gimme' is a casual way of saying 'give me'.

Comment: @KateBunting I updated the question, Madam

Comment: I'm guessing this is a rap because it's nonsense. I've never heard anyone use that expression.

Comment: It looks like a one-off expression suggesting holding the hands out either to ask for something, or to grab it.

Comment: @MicahWindsor: it's not nonsense, it's poetry.

Comment: Why do you answer questions in the comment area?

Comment: Max, please take note of how to ask a question properly in English. I've been seeing more and more "What means x" in the questions and it's quite distressing. I think your question is legitimate as it would not be in any dictionary.

Comment: @ColinFine Poetry is wonderful, but *gimme* is not a noun. It is grammatical nonsense.

Comment: @MicahWindsor: Any verb can be nouned. It is grammatical (though probably not standard) and not nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Question correction]: What does "hands full of gimme" mean?

There is a thing people say when another only asks for things all the time:

You are always saying gimme, gimme, gimme. Which means: give me. When you say: Give me x, you hold out your hand. It means **greedy** here.

The songwriter has made an object out of the verb and pronoun: Give me [x].

*gimme* is a way to write **give me** for those who speak fast and leave out the letter v.

In everyday speech, you might hear it even from a 'well-educated speaker".

It's similar to wanna for want to and gonna for going to.

"Hey, gimme that. That's my ice-cream,not yours!"

In other words politicians are greedy people and liars.